# Risk/Information Regarding Copyright/Trademark Violation

Tags: copyright, software, trademark, terms-of-service, music

I have previously participated in the illicit accessing of files (music, etc.) that were most likely copyrighted/trademarked/etc. as well as the distribution of modified versions of these files (remixes, etc).

I wanted to know, in a general sense (if possible to say, since Terms of Service can vary), if I would be at risk of losing my access/permission to access the pieces of software used in creating/making said modifications or if because the software companies would most likely not be the ones trying to make a copyright claim, the actions involving the illicit files and the distribution of said files would just be something that's discouraged, but not punished by them?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you still distributing the infringing material? All it takes is one copyright holder to notice and sue you.

Comment: I don't think that I am still intentionally distributing the material and if so, it isn't to my knowledge except for one possible sample of some drums that I used not thinking it was copyrighted, but on referring back to it, there's a small possibility that it may be copyrighted/possibility trademarked/etc.

Comment: I don't see how a sample (a sound recording) could be trademarked.

Comment: Hard to figure out what you mean here. I guess you are using software that licensed audio recordings from artists for the software user to use for noncommercial uses [use]? First step is to read the software's EULA. Does this software allow you to pay extra to use the samples for commercial projects and you just didn't? It's impossible to know what agreement the software company had with the artists so I don't think anyone can help you much with the limited information you provided. This isn't informal legal counsel for the purpose of winning your bounty, this is just pro-bono pro-tipping.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, as a clarification of what I mean, I used a piece of software (along with multiple other pieces of software inside said initial piece of software) that allowed me to digitally modify audio files. Some of said audio files (that were most likely copyrighted) were acquired through illicit means such as using another piece of software to download from larger video sites. Some of these modified works were then redistributed, but I have made attempts to remove them from circulation.

Comment: What I'm looking for, if possible, is if there is any sort of general idea that can assist me as going through each individual terms of service for each piece of software that I may have used at some point to modify said files would be a lot of searching.

Comment: If you got the audio files from a different source then the software has nothing to do with anything. There is nothing illegal about modifying audio files. The DMCA is ridiculous and makes it illegal to modify certain copyrighted works, but that involves circumventing DRM.

Although I'm not an expert. But my guess is the software companies will say that they didn't make the tools for copyright infringement and have nothing to do with it.

They could report your information to those investigating the copyright infringement, though. Particularly if there's a court order.